# What came first, the covariance or the correlation matrix?

Tags: correlation, standard-deviation, covariance, covariance-matrix, correlation-matrix

Covariance can be calculated from correlation and correlation can be calculated from covariance. Is it sufficient to refer to them as only transformations of one another? Is one considered more of a basis for calculating the other than the other is of it?

Comment: Covariance can *not* be computed from correlation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correlation needs one step more to be computed than covariance, so I'd say that correlation comes from covariance. This is also the way it has been taught to me in university.

You can consider correlation as a normalised version of covariance, while covariance retains the scale of the original variables and their units of measurment.